# In Typescript / React, how do I create a component with generic types for its props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a relatively generic component. Its definition looks something like the following:

```
export type CheckboxItem = {
  label: string,
  code: string,
};

export type CheckboxesProps = {
  items: CheckboxItem[],
  handleStateChange: (selected: (CheckboxItem['code'])[]) => void,

};

export interface CheckboxState<T>  {
  [key: CheckboxItem['code']]: boolean,
}


export default function Checkboxes({items, handleStateChange}: CheckboxesProps) {
    const [state, setState] = useState<CheckboxState>(items.reduce((stateObj: CheckboxState, item: CheckboxItem) => {
      stateObj[item.code] = false;
      return stateObj;
    }, {}));

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      setState({
        ...state,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
      });
      handleStateChange(Object.keys(state).filter(key => state[key]));
  };
...
}
```

This works until I try invoking Checkboxes with items that are Object Constants (not sure correct typescript terminology):

```
// within another component
export const PrimaryNeeds = {
  foodAllergies: 'foodAllergies',
  foodRestrictions: 'foodRestrictions',
  medicineAllergies: 'medicineAllergies',
  medicalConditions: 'medicalConditions',
  phobias: 'phobias',
  other: 'other',
} as const;

// type checkboxItems = {
//    label: PrimaryNeeds[keyof PrimaryNeeds]
//    code: keyof PrimaryNeeds, 
// }
// The above type isn't actually in my code, I simply do the following instead:

export type PrimaryNeedsCheckboxesProps = {
  langCode: keyof typeof LanguageCodes,
  handlePrimaryNeedsChanged: (selected: (keyof typeof PrimaryNeeds)[]) => void,
}

export default function PrimaryNeedsCheckboxes({langCode, handlePrimaryNeedsChanged}: PrimaryNeedsCheckboxesProps) {

   const checkboxItems = (Object.keys(PrimaryNeeds) as (keyof PrimaryNeeds)[]).map((needKey: keyof PrimaryNeeds) => {
        return {
          label: primaryNeeds[needKey],
          code: needKey,
        };
      });
    // ...
   return (
     <Checkboxes items={checkboxItems} handleStateChange={handlePrimaryNeedsChanged} />
   )
```

Now I get an error about type mismatch between the type string not being assignable to the I guess "union type" of the PrimaryNeeds keys:

```
Type '(selected: ("foodAllergies" | "foodRestrictions" | "medicineAllergies" | "medicalConditions" | "phobias" | "other")[]) => void' is not assignable to type '(selected: string[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'selected' and 'selected' are incompatible.
    Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '("foodAllergies" | "foodRestrictions" | "medicineAllergies" | "medicalConditions" | "phobias" | "other")[]'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"foodAllergies" | "foodRestrictions" | "medicineAllergies" | "medicalConditions" | "phobias" | "other"'.
```

I tried to set a generic type so that the Checkbox component CheckboxItem object property types could depend on a passed-in type, but then I ran into typescript not allowing generic types to be used as index:

```
export type CheckboxItem<T> = {
  label: keyof T,
  code: T[keyof T],
};
export type CheckboxesProps<T>= {
  items: CheckboxItem<T>[],
  handleStateChange: (selected: (CheckboxItem<T>['code'])[]) => void,
};
// error points to "key" below
export interface CheckboxState<T>  {
  [key: CheckboxItem<T>['code']]: boolean,
}

An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.
```

I read the [mapped object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) documentation but didn't see how that could help, though I don't exactly understand the mechanism of **how** they're supposed to help either. Nor do I understand the issue around using a generic type as an index signature parameter - it seems to be what I want, though I guess there's a good reason.

I did try using the bit recommended in Key Remapping:

```
export interface CheckboxState<T>  {
  [K in T]?: boolean,
}
```

But Typescript didn't like that either:

```
A mapped type may not declare properties or methods.
```

**How can I create a generic type for these props?** Or, is that what I should even be doing here?

Comment: please include or remove the useState. Also `formLabel` doesn't exist in the props

Comment: also `checkboxItems` and `handlePrimaryNeedsChanged` shouldn't be a type

Comment: Thanks for catching that, updated. I'm trying to keep it to its reproducible bits

Comment: `checkboxItems` and  `handlePrimaryNeedsChanged` are still types, but you are using them as variables

Comment: here, updated to include function definition for PrimaryNeedCheckboxes component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type` and `interface` in TypeScript are [mostly equivalent](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces), but mapped types are an exception - they have to be *types*.

So

```
export interface CheckboxState<T> {
  [key in keyof T]: boolean
}
```

throws an error, but

```
export type CheckboxState<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: boolean
}
```

works.

(It also looks like your example code may be confusing codes and labels - your commented-out `checkboxItems` uses code as the keys and label as the values (I assume this is what you need), but your `CheckboxItems` generic type uses label as the keys and code as the value.)

Comment: Ugh I can't believe it was just that... I keep glossing over the interface/type difference in the typescript docs, I knew it would screw me over one day!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could start with a `useCheckboxes` hook -

```
type CheckboxesState = Record<string, boolean>

type UseCheckboxes<T extends CheckboxesState> = {
    keys: Array<keyof T>,
    get: (key: keyof T) => boolean,
    set: (key: keyof T, value: boolean) => void,
}

function useCheckboxes<T extends CheckboxesState>(init: (() => T) | T): UseCheckboxes<T> {
    const [state, setState] = useState(init)
    return useMemo(
        () => ({
            keys: Object.keys(state),
            get: (key) => state[key],
            set: (key, value) => { setState(s => ({ ...s, [key]: value })) },
        }),
        [state],
    )
}
```

Each instance of `useCheckboxes` returns a unique type -

```
const mydata = useCheckboxes({
    turbo: true,
    debug: false,
})

// mydata : UseCheckboxes<{ turbo: true, debug: false }>
```

We get helpful type auto-completions when using the `set` and `get` methods -

[image: 1]

Now you can write your `Checkboxes` component. `UseCheckboxes` gives us everything we need to iterate and display the checkboxes, and create an `onChange` handler for each checkbox -

```
function Checkboxes<T extends CheckboxesState>(props: { items: UseCheckboxes<T> }) {
    const { items } = props
    return (
        <div>
            {items.keys.map(key => (
                <label key={key}>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={items.get(key)}
                    value={key}
                    onChange={() => items.set(key, !items.get(key))}
                  />
                  {key}
                </label>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here's a complete demo you can run in your browser -

```js
const { useMemo, useState } = React

function useCheckboxes(init) {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState(init);
    return React.useMemo(() => ({
        keys: Object.keys(state),
        get: (key) => state[key],
        set: (key, value) => { setState(s => (Object.assign(Object.assign({}, s), { [key]: value }))); },
    }), [state]);
}

function Checkboxes(props) {
    const { items } = props
    return (
        <div>
            {items.keys.map(key => (
                <label key={key}>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={items.get(key)}
                    value={key}
                    onChange={() => items.set(key, !items.get(key))}
                  />
                  {key}
                </label>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

function App() {
    const checkboxes = useCheckboxes({
        foo: true,
        bar: false,
    });
    return <Checkboxes items={checkboxes} />
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```